# How to stop php-cli-server's request logging

Tags: php

I am using php 7.4 and I am trying to built a local devserver with php-cli
I can log requests in my routing file but php-server always logs requests like;

```
[Fri Jun 25 12:49:59 2021] PHP 7.4.20 Development Server (http://localhost:8100) started
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51057 Accepted
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51058 Accepted
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] Connection: ::1:51058 [200]: /
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51058 Closing
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51059 Accepted
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51060 Accepted
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51061 Accepted
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51062 Accepted
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51063 Accepted
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51064 Accepted
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51059 Closing
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51060 Closing
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51061 Closing
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51062 Closing
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51063 Closing
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51065 Accepted
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51064 Closing
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51066 Accepted
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51065 Closing
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51067 Accepted
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51066 Closing
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51068 Accepted
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51069 Accepted
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51067 Closing
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51068 Closing
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51069 Closing
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51070 Accepted
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51071 Accepted
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51070 Closing
[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] [::1]:51071 Closing
[Fri Jun 25 12:51:01 2021] [::1]:51057 Closed without sending a request; it was probably just an unused speculative preconnection
[Fri Jun 25 12:51:01 2021] [::1]:51057 Closing
```

The `[Fri Jun 25 12:50:01 2021] Connection: ::1:51058 [200]: /` part is logged by the router.
how can I close other logs? please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I have read about starting php server in silent mode. I guess we can use -q flag to avoid request logging which comes by php-fpm.

I am starting my server with a little function like;

```
function start() {
    exec("php -S address:port .router.php")
}
```

And if I want to use quiet mode I need to add -q flag in this function.
Like;

```
function start() {
    exec("php -q -S address:port .router.php")
}
```

This not solves my problem. Actually this kills every error_log() function. Please find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch the server in quiet mode (-q) and add `error_log = /dev/stderr` to your php.ini config to keep the errors logging to docker.